# How to query tags and tag groups similar to faceted search

Tags: sql, sql-server, faceted-search

How do I do the following faceted search statement:

SELECT * FROM animals WHERE `animal is assigned to tag ('brown' or 'black') AND tag ('male')`

given the following table structure:

## Animals (i.e. 'Max', 'Toby', 'Buster')

id | name

## AnimalTags (Map Table)

animalsId | tagsId

## Tags (i.e 'black', 'brown', 'white', 'dog', 'cat', 'male', 'female')

id | tag

## TagGroups (Map Table)

tagsId | tagsGroupId

## TagGroup (i.e. 'Color' and 'Gender')

id | tagGroup

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM animals
INNER JOIN animalTags ON animalTags.animalsId  = animals.id
INNER JOIN tags       ON animalTags.tagsId     = tags.id
INNER JOIN tagGroups  ON tagGroups.tagsId      = tags.id
INNER JOIN tagGroup   ON tagGroups.tagGroupsId = tagGroup.id
```

and then something with GROUP BY and HAVING I assume to say something like:

```
GROUP BY tagGroup
???
```

Need this to be flexible where eventually this becomes a stored procedure where I simply pass in tag ids like `51,69,88` and the stored procedure does does its magic.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have been in eascally this situation where you need to either pass values that have been selected or if none selected assume all. Problem being I am currently on my phone feel free to message me and I will be happy to assist later tonight if still needed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do (an example) if you want to get all animals having tagged as `'brown','black','male'`. You need to `join` to the mapping table `AnimalTags` before a `join` to the `Tags` table. Again, I have chosed to do a `INNER JOIN` considering that every animal will be associated to 1 or more tag. if that's not the case you may consider doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT a.* FROM animals a
join AnimalTags at on a.id = at.animalsid
join Tags t on t.id = at.tagsid
where t.tag in ('brown','black','male')
```

Comment: That I know, but the challenge I'm after is doing it with tag groups. I'm looking for ('brown' OR 'black') AND ('male'). Anything in the same group should be an OR, and anything in a different group should be an AND. In english terms if a user doesn't select a color we assume they're ok with any color and don't specify any WHERE clause. As soon as they specify a color we restrict the animals to only those assigned that color tag. As soon as they select a 2nd or 3rd color that means they're ok with 'black' OR 'brown' OR 'tan'. Now adding a tag from another group is not "OR", but rather "AND"...